# RubyでGIF画像を結合したい

Tags: ruby, 画像

GIF画像をくっつけるだけの処理を行いたいのですが、やり方がわかりません。
調べてもRMagickやMiniMagickなど、ImageMagickが必要なものしか見つけられませんでした。
処理自体はシンプルなので、ImageMagickを使わない方法があればそれを使いたいです。
ImageMagickを使っていないGemを使う方法でも問題ありません。

やろうとしているのは以下のようなものです。

```
+---+
| A |
+---+

  +

+---+
| B |
+---+

  ↓

+-------+
| A   B |
+-------+
```

サンプルコードやサイトなど教えていただけると幸いです。
よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 1):

[Ruby/GD](https://github.com/Spakman/ruby-gd/blob/master/readme.ja)は目的にかないますでしょうか？

この拡張ライブラリーは過去、一時的に`GIF`を取り扱えない時期がありましたが、現在は再び`GIF`の読み書きが出来る様になっています。

`concatinate`や`+`は無いかも知れませんが、それぞれのイメージサイズを取得して、新規イメージを作成し`copyMerge`メソッドあたりを使えば目的の動作が出来るのではないかと思います。